# after $make do i need to transfer to /usr/local/bin all files or just the executable?

Tags: 18.04, make

I know this is probably an ignorant question but I ve been always wondering:
after downloading and running `make` on a linux software (e.g. https://github.com/scapella/trimal) - do I need to copy to `usr/local/bin` the executables **only** or the executables **and all the other files** in that directory that were created after running `make` ?

How can I know that copying only the executable is enough? even if it is running, how can i know that it is running properly and it does not need to find the path of where I originally ran `make`
I am asking cause many times this is not clear...

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help. I do not know what you know already. https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to copy the executable files, to a location that is on your `PATH` such as `/usr/local/bin/` or `~/bin/`.

*In general*, software may install some or all of the following:

- executables to a suitable `bin/` directory
- shared library files to a suitable `lib/` directory
- documentation to a `man/` and or `info/` directory
- configuration files to `etc/`
- other files to a `share/` directory

In that case, the developers usually provide an `install` target (run as `make install`) to distribute files into the appropriate directories.

In the case of the `trimal` software, there does not appear to be anything to install apart from the three executable files `trimal`, `readal`, and `statal` and no `install` target is provided.

Answer (score 1):

What to do after `make` is usually described by the developper

For your example, please see the [README.md](https://github.com/scapella/trimal/blob/trimAl/README) file located in the sources root folder :

> By default, 'make' compiles the source code of trimAl and readAl in the
> current directory. After that, you can either add to PATH the current
> directory or move these files to '/usr/local/bin' or to '/usr/bin' using
> root privileges.

If you build a driver module instead of a "classic" executable, the path is not `bin/` but something like `/etc/modules` because read by the kernel at boot. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a cleanly programmed Open Source project should provide a `make install` target that does that for you: A user should not need to know where to copy which files.

In that project, they did not go through that trouble; they didn't even provide any instructions. I'd call that sloppy and unprofessional.

The `makefile` lets us make an educated guess:

https://github.com/scapella/trimal/blob/trimAl/source/makefile#L15

So 3 executables are built. They don't need much in the way of libraries:

https://github.com/scapella/trimal/blob/trimAl/source/makefile#L15

only *libm*, the math library that is installed on every system anyway.

You certainly don't want the `.o` files; that are compiled object files needed for linking the binaries.

You may want the scripts, though:

https://github.com/scapella/trimal/tree/trimAl/scripts

Some contain some documentation in the header what they do. There may be some additional documentation about the whole project in some other place, but the official project site https://trimal.cgenomics.org/ seems to be down.